# How do you add different types of values?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to set an imageview's width (CGRect) and a NSLayoutconstraint, and then compare that value to the device's screen size. How do I do this, being that they are not of the same type?

Comment: add proportional width to superview...its simple.

Comment: LEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERRROY JENKINS go do a search in stack over flow!

Answer (score 0):

For all ye who are in the same boat I was:

```
constraint.constant + UIImageview.bounds.width > screenSize.width
```

constraint is the NSLayoutconstraint, then the image width, and then the screen size. Be forewarned: screenSize.width seems to be measured in pixels.